# Find the maximum length of a line segment enclosed in a given area

Tags: coordinate-systems

$A = \{ (x, y) : x = u + v , y = v , (u^2) + (v^2) \le 1 \}$  . Then what is the maximum length of a line segment enclosed in this area?

My friend suggested the answer $\sqrt{5}$, but I think it should be greater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $x = u+v$
- $y = v$
- $u^2+v^2 \le 1$

---

- $u^2+v^2 \le 1 \implies u,v$ are inside the unit circle, therefore:

  - $-1 \leq u \leq 1$
  - $-1 \leq v \leq 1$
  - $-\sqrt{2} \leq u+v \leq \sqrt{2}$

[image]

---

- Therefore:

  - $-\sqrt{2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{2}$
  - $-1 \leq y \leq 1$

[image]

---

The longest line within this rectangle is the diagonal of course, which is equal to:

$$\sqrt{(2\sqrt{2})^2+2^2} = \sqrt{12}$$

Comment: Should'nt u+v be less than $2^.5$ rather than 2 times that

Comment: please elaborate the step    −2√2 ≤ u+v ≤ 2√2

Comment: @abstract: Note that $u+v = u\pm\sqrt{1-u^2}$. So take the function $f(u) = u+\sqrt{1-u^2}$, calculate the derivative $f'(u)$ and find the maximum value. Then take the function $f(u) = u-\sqrt{1-u^2}$, calculate the derivative $f'(u)$ and find the minimum value.

Comment: @abstract: My mistake with the range of $u+v$. Please see updated answer...

Comment: @user142634: Not sure what you mean by $2^5$, but the range of $u+v$ is indeed half of what I initially wrote; now fixed.

Comment: Its 2^(.5) , point was not visible i guess

Comment: @user142634: OK, I got you. You need to use LaTex, which would make expressions like this visible. For example, in order to represent 2^0.5, you encapsulate the entire expression with \$ marks on both sides, then you encapsulate each operand with curly brackets. In any case, I have fixed the answer above from $2\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{2}$... Thanks :)